# Rails: Trouble with route helper for DELETE action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html) I see them use a route helper for the `DELETE` action: `<%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete %>`. However, when I try to use a similar route helper to delete comments, it doesn't work:

```
<p><%= comment.body %><%= link_to article_comment_path(comment.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} do %>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<% end %></p>
```

Why doesn't it work? This is what I get when I run `rake routes`. The tutorial says that the names in the prefix column "trickle down". So the lines with empty prefixes get the prefix from the nearest above prefix. So isn't `article_comment_path(<id>)` the right route helper?

The error I'm getting is `ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, :article_id=>4, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):`, so it is trying to go to the `show` action instead of the `destroy` action.

```
~/practice/blog >>  rake routes
              Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
                root GET    /                                                 articles#index
    article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting a nested resource you have to specify both resources ids. In your code, add `article.id` to `article_comment_path`

Your view code should look likes:

```
<p><%= comment.body %><%= link_to article_comment_path(article.id, comment.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} do %>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<% end %></p>
```